# Matroids and minimal dependence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matroids

> Let $M = (E, S)$ be a matroid and $D$ be the set of all minimal dependent sets of $M$. Prove that if $A_1, A_2 \in D$ such that $A_1 \neq A_2$, and if $x \in A_1 \cup A_2$, then there exists $B \in D$ satisfying $B \subseteq (A_1 \cup A_2) \setminus \{x\}$.

**Solution:**

Assume there is a $C = A_1 \cup A_2$. Because, $A_1, A_2 \in D$, it follows that $C \in D$. This implies that $B \subset C$, which means that $B$ is independent and therefore we conclude that $B \notin D$.

My proof looks a bit vague and different, and I don't even know whether it is actually true. Any ideas?

Comment: If $A_1\ne A_2$, then $A_1\cup A_2$ is *not* in $D$: it’s dependent, but it’s not minimal dependent, because all minimal dependent sets are the same size.

Comment: So therefore, assuming $|A_1| = |A_2| + 1$, and $x \in A_1$. We get that $A_1$ is also not minimal. And that $B = A_2$, where both are minimal. But according to this we can get that $A_2 \subset A_1$, which in turn will mean that $A_2$ is independent and not in $D$. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the question phrased correctly?

See the following link: Preposition 1.2

http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18438F09/lec9.pdf

This link also contains a proof for preposition 1.2

It is the same axiom, but with intersection in place of union

Comment: I don't believe it's the same thing.

Comment: @portal: Yes, the second part of Proposition 1 is exactly your problem: *circuit* is the same thing is *minimal dependent set*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: The problem is the question in the link is phrased slightly different...it involves an intersection and not a union. I am wondering if the question in OP is written incorrectly.

Comment: The proposition in the linked PDF deals with the hard case. If $x\in A_1\setminus A_2$, you can just take $B=A_2$. Similarly, if $x\in A_2\setminus A_1$, you can take $B=A_1$. Thus, it’s only when $x\in A_1\cap A_2$ that you really have anything much to prove.

Comment: I checked again, and yes my problem involves union.

Comment: @portal: I know. But if $x\in A_1\cup A_2$, then either $x\in A_1\setminus A_2$, $x\in A_2\setminus A_1$, or $x\in A_1\cap A_2$. I pointed out why the first two cases are pretty trivial, and the argument in the PDF takes care of the third.

Comment: What does it want to say with this part: Extend X − f to a maximal independent set in X ∪ Y? How can we extend? Or is it just assuming?